# How to set Service mssql-server to start on boot?

Tags: 16.04, services, mssql

How can i set Service mssql-server to start on boot

```
    root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-lon1-01:/etc/init.d# update-rc.d  mssql-server enable
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for mssql-server
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-lon1-01:/etc/init.d# update-rc.d system.ctl mssql-server enable
usage: update-rc.d [-n] [-f] <basename> remove
       update-rc.d [-n] <basename> disable|enable [S|2|3|4|5]
                -n: not really
                -f: force

The disable|enable API is not stable and might change in the future.
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-lon1-01:/etc/init.d# update-rc.d system.ctl mssql-server -f
usage: update-rc.d [-n] [-f] <basename> remove
       update-rc.d [-n] <basename> disable|enable [S|2|3|4|5]
                -n: not really
                -f: force
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 16.04, as reported in the question tag, you should use systemctl instead. To enable the service at startup:

```
systemctl enable mssql
```

To disable the service at startup:

```
systemctl disable mssql
```

Maybe the service name would be mssql-server, so try first with mysql then with mysqld

Comment: Worked with systemctl enable mssql-server